# How to decide whether to use Spark RDD filter or not

Tags: apache-spark

I am using spark to read and analyse a data file, file contains data like following:

- 1,unit1,category1_1,100
- 2,unit1,category1_2,150
- 3,unit2,category2_1,200
- 4,unit3,category3_1,200
- 5,unit3,category3_2,300

The file contains around 20 million records. If user input unit or category, spark need filter the data by inputUnit or inputCategory.

Solution 1:

```
sc.textFile(file).map(line => {
  val Array(id,unit,category,amount) = line.split(",")
  if ( (StringUtils.isNotBlank(inputUnit) && unit != inputUnit ) ||
    (StringUtils.isNotBlank(inputCategory) && category != inputCategory)){
    null
  } else {
    val obj = new MyObj(id,unit,category,amount)
    (id,obj)
  }
}).filter(_!=null).collectAsMap()
```

Solution 2:

```
var rdd = sc.textFile(file).map(line => {
  val (id,unit,category,amount) = line.split(",")
  (id,unit,category,amount)
})

if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(inputUnit)) {
  rdd = rdd.filter(_._2 == inputUnit)
}
if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(inputCategory)) {
  rdd = rdd.filter(_._3 == inputCategory)
}

rdd.map(e => {
  val obj = new MyObject(e._1, e._2, e._3, e._4)
  (e._1, obj)
}).collectAsMap
```

I want to understand, which solution is better, or both of them are poor? If both are poor, how to make a good one? Personally, I think second one is better, but I am not quite sure whether it is nice to declare a rdd as var... (I am new to Spark, and I am using Spark 1.5.0 and Scala 2.10.4 to write the code, this is my first time asking a question in StackOverFlow, feel free to edit if it is not well formatted) Thanks.

Comment: If you dealing with huge records, I would recommend to use **DataFrames** in spark rather than RDD,  as dataframes dynamically constructs infinite datasets. This can be achieved using **spark2.0**. Also you need to use spark Sql to register to any jdbc to display data in dataframes.

Comment: Hi,Praveen, I can not upgrade spark to 2.0 at the moment, it is an existing project, I am just try to add more functions ...

Comment: Dataframes available since spark 1.3 version,  you can try that option.